# Joomla loginform gives 500 error on bad attempt

Tags: joomla

At http://falkotl76.seventysix.axc.nl/youcollect/nl/inloggen I have a joomla loginform as a menu-item and it shows well.
When I make an attempt to login without any details it gives me a 500error and I cant figure out how to solve that.

Does anybody know how I can solve this ?

Thanks in regards,

Falko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I had the same issue and I fixed it by giving write permission to error.php file.

Path is - `your joomla folder/log/error.php`

Also make sure log and tmp path is correct in configuration.php

Comment: @user1456158:good to know.You can also accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the client side validation javascript library.  Create a template override for the com_users login view file default_login.php.  At the top, add the JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation'); line to load the library. And then add the class 'form-validate' to the form element.  Below is an example:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
?>
<div class="login<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx?>">
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
    <h1>
        <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?>
    </h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($this->params->get('logindescription_show') == 1 && str_replace(' ', '', $this->params->get('login_description')) != '') || $this->params->get('login_image') != '') : ?>
    <div class="login-description">
    <?php endif ; ?>

        <?php if($this->params->get('logindescription_show') == 1) : ?>
            <?php echo $this->params->get('login_description'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (($this->params->get('login_image')!='')) :?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('login_image')); ?>" class="login-image" alt="<?php echo JTEXT::_('COM_USER_LOGIN_IMAGE_ALT')?>"/>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($this->params->get('logindescription_show') == 1 && str_replace(' ', '', $this->params->get('login_description')) != '') || $this->params->get('login_image') != '') : ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ; ?>

    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login'); ?>" method="post" class="form-validate">

        <fieldset>
            <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('credentials') as $field): ?>
                <?php if (!$field->hidden): ?>
                    <div class="login-fields"><?php echo $field->label; ?>
                    <?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if (JPluginHelper::isEnabled('system', 'remember')) : ?>
            <div class="login-fields">
                <label id="remember-lbl" for="remember"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_ME') ?></label>
                <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"  alt="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_ME') ?>" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo JText::_('JLOGIN'); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_RESET'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=remind'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_REMIND'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
        $usersConfig = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
        if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration')) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration'); ?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_REGISTER'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added a couple of links of template overrides for reference.  This should solve your issue.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides